# 401 error while making a call using jain sip library android

Tags: android, sip, jain-sip

I have made a sip client using jain sip library. I am able to register the client and here is the respose from the sip server

```
31-May-2015 19:00:14.257    [CM504001]: Endpoint Extn:401: new contact is registered. Contact(s): [sip:401@192.168.1.3:5080 / 401]
```

Now when i click on call button I get following response from the server.

```
31-May-2015 19:05:18.118    [CM504002]: Endpoint Extn:401: a contact is unregistered. Contact(s): []
31-May-2015 19:01:04.867    Leg L:1.1[Unknown:] is terminated: Cause: BYE from PBX
31-May-2015 19:01:04.812    [CM502001]: Source info: From: <sip:401@192.168.1.3:5080>;tag=Tzt0ZEP92; To: <sip:400>
31-May-2015 19:01:04.812    [CM503013]: Call(C:1): Incoming call rejected, caller is unknown; msg=Ivite-IN Recv Req INVITE from 192.168.1.3:5080 tid=-343937-0429701b5f2f8b0122a365a56ac5d974 Call-ID=c0335e9c736e5785826955de9f0b6ae7@192.168.1.3:
            INVITE sip:400 SIP/2.0
            Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.3:5080;rport=5080;branch=z9hG4bK-343937-0429701b5f2f8b0122a365a56ac5d974
            Max-Forwards: 70
            Route: <sip:192.168.1.7:5060;transport=udp;lr>
            Contact: <sip:401@192.168.1.3:5080>
            To: <sip:400>
            From: <sip:401@192.168.1.3:5080>;tag=Tzt0ZEP92
            Call-ID: c0335e9c736e5785826955de9f0b6ae7@192.168.1.3
            CSeq: 2 INVITE
            Call-Info: <http://www.antd.nist.gov>
            Content-Type: application/sdp
            Proxy-Authorization: Digest username="401",realm="3CXPhoneSystem",nonce="414d535c0b7b9a9497:e49c5068970045631f39bac52ed74673",uri="sip:400",response="6e376a0d4dc10ffdc584d3b697aadb0c",algorithm=MD5
            Supported: replaces, outbound
            Content-Length: 246
31-May-2015 19:01:04.343    [CM500002]: Unidentified incoming call. Review INVITE and adjust source identification:
            Invite-UNK Recv Req INVITE from 192.168.1.3:5080 tid=-343937-fc99c27fff992fb02c73b014c7b6a23d Call-ID=c0335e9c736e5785826955de9f0b6ae7@192.168.1.3:
            INVITE sip:400 SIP/2.0
            Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.3:5080;rport=5080;branch=z9hG4bK-343937-fc99c27fff992fb02c73b014c7b6a23d
            Max-Forwards: 70
            Route: <sip:192.168.1.7:5060;transport=udp;lr>
            Contact: <sip:401@192.168.1.3:5080>
            To: <sip:400>
            From: <sip:401@192.168.1.3:5080>;tag=Tzt0ZEP92
            Call-ID: c0335e9c736e5785826955de9f0b6ae7@192.168.1.3
            CSeq: 1 INVITE
            Call-Info: <http://www.antd.nist.gov>
            Content-Type: application/sdp
            Supported: replaces, outbound
            Content-Length: 246
```

Part of code responsible for processing response is as follows

```
public void processResponse(ResponseEvent arg0) {

        Response response = (Response) arg0.getResponse();
        System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());

        Dialog responseDialog = null;
        ClientTransaction tid = arg0.getClientTransaction();
        if (tid != null) {
            responseDialog = tid.getDialog();
        } else {
            responseDialog = arg0.getDialog();
        }
        CSeqHeader cseq = (CSeqHeader) response.getHeader(CSeqHeader.NAME);
        if (response.getStatusCode() == Response.PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED
                || response.getStatusCode() == Response.UNAUTHORIZED) {
            AuthenticationHelper authenticationHelper = ((SipStackExt) sipStack)
                    .getAuthenticationHelper(
                            new AccountManagerImpl(sipProfile.getSipUserName(),
                                    sipProfile.getRemoteIp(), sipProfile
                                            .getSipPassword()), headerFactory);

            try {
                ClientTransaction inviteTid = authenticationHelper
                        .handleChallenge(response, tid, sipProvider, 5, true);


                inviteTid.sendRequest();




            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                System.out.println("a: null error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SipException e) {
                System.out.println("b: null error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else if (response.getStatusCode() == Response.OK) {
            if (cseq.getMethod().equals(Request.INVITE)) {
                System.out.println("Dialog after 200 OK  " + dialog);
                System.out.println("c: invite  " + dialog);
                try {
                    Request ackRequest = responseDialog.createAck(cseq
                            .getSeqNumber());
                    System.out.println("Sending ACK");
                    responseDialog.sendAck(ackRequest);
                    byte[] rawContent = response.getRawContent();
                    String sdpContent = new String(rawContent, "UTF-8");
                    SDPAnnounceParser parser = new SDPAnnounceParser(sdpContent);
                    SessionDescriptionImpl sessiondescription = parser.parse();
                    MediaDescription incomingMediaDescriptor = (MediaDescription) sessiondescription
                            .getMediaDescriptions(false).get(0);
                    int rtpPort = incomingMediaDescriptor.getMedia()
                            .getMediaPort();
                    dispatchSipEvent(new SipEvent(this,
                            SipEventType.CALL_CONNECTED, "", "", rtpPort));
                } catch (InvalidArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SipException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SdpException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else if (cseq.getMethod().equals(Request.CANCEL)) {
                if (dialog.getState() == DialogState.CONFIRMED) {
                    // oops cancel went in too late. Need to hang up the
                    // dialog.
                    System.out
                            .println("Sending BYE -- cancel went in too late !!");
                    Request byeRequest = null;
                    try {
                        byeRequest = dialog.createRequest(Request.BYE);
                    } catch (SipException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    ClientTransaction ct = null;
                    try {
                        ct = sipProvider.getNewClientTransaction(byeRequest);
                    } catch (TransactionUnavailableException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        dialog.sendRequest(ct);
                    } catch (TransactionDoesNotExistException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SipException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }
        } else if (response.getStatusCode() == Response.DECLINE) {
            System.out.println("CALL DECLINED");
            dispatchSipEvent(new SipEvent(this, SipEventType.DECLINED, "", ""));

        } else if (response.getStatusCode() == Response.NOT_FOUND) {
            System.out.println("NOT FOUND");
        } else if (response.getStatusCode() == Response.ACCEPTED) {
            System.out.println("ACCEPTED");
        } else if (response.getStatusCode() == Response.BUSY_HERE) {
            System.out.println("BUSY");
            dispatchSipEvent(new SipEvent(this, SipEventType.BUSY_HERE, "", ""));
        } else if (response.getStatusCode() == Response.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE) {
            System.out.println("BUSY");
            dispatchSipEvent(new SipEvent(this,
                    SipEventType.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, "", ""));
        }
    }
```

I have been struggling to make this thing work but still no luck. Please help.

Comment: Most servers will never accept destination sip:400 you should rewrite that sip:400@somedomain

Comment: @VladimirRalev I used sip:400@192.168.1.4:5062 but still same error.

Comment: You should post the new logs. Basically you must configure your 3CX to handle these calls. Make sure the users exist and are registered under the appropriate IP:port.